# Generating ssh keys from asp.net core

Tags: c#, security, ssh, asp.net-core

I have started to create a console app, which I am testing locally on my mac.

The idea is to generate an ssh key and structure the storage of these keys within the `.ssh` folder. My thought behind this is for my digital ocean ssh keys, and so I am using a folder structure dictated by the droplet name and user.

i.e

```
/users/user.name/.ssh/<droplet1>/root
/users/user.name/.ssh/<droplet1>/git
/users/user.name/.ssh/<droplet2>/root
/users/user.name/.ssh/<droplet2>/git
```

I have used asp.net core. I am assuming the `.ssh` folder is directly below the location of the `$HOME` directory. I have also assumed the ssh-keygen program is located at `/usr/bin/ssh-keygen`

My questions relate to

1. The security of generating the ssh key in this manner. Is it better to use in-built methods to generate the ssh key?
2. Is it safe to assume that the `.ssh` folder is located under the users directory (for linux platforms)?
3. General structure of the program and overall thoughts
4. I plan to extend this to automatically add the location, username and box name to `.ssh/config` allowing me to then do `ssh droplet1-root` to login to droplet1 as root user.

My simple program is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace gssh
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ValidateCompatibility();

            string homePath = GetHomePathOrExit();

            Console.WriteLine($"The users home directory is: {homePath}\n");

            // Check the state of .ssh directory
            string sshDirectory, configLocation;
            bool configFileExists;
            CheckStateOfSshDirectory(homePath, out sshDirectory, out configLocation, out configFileExists);

            string locationOfSshKey = GetLocationOfKeyOrExit(sshDirectory);

            // Check that the directory does not exsist otherwise exit
            // Create Directory
            // generate key

            if (Directory.Exists(locationOfSshKey))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key location already exists, exiting...");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            Directory.CreateDirectory(locationOfSshKey);
            Console.WriteLine("Directory Created");

            CreateSshKey(locationOfSshKey);

            Console.WriteLine(configLocation);
            Console.WriteLine(configFileExists);
        }

        private static void CreateSshKey(string locationOfSshKey)
        {
            //Create process
            System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            //strCommand is path and file name of command to run
            pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "/usr/bin/ssh-keygen";

            //strCommandParameters are parameters to pass to program
            pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-t rsa -b 4096 -N '' -f {locationOfSshKey}/key";

            pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            //Start the process
            pProcess.Start();

            //Wait for process to finish
            pProcess.WaitForExit();
        }

        private static string GetLocationOfKeyOrExit(string sshDirectory)
        {
            Console.Write("What is the name of the machine/service the ssh key will be used for? ");
            var machine = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("What user/role ssh key will be used for? ");
            var user = Console.ReadLine();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(machine) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("One or more of your options was empty");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            string locationOfSshKey = $"{sshDirectory}/{machine}/{user}";

            Console.WriteLine("The location of your ssh key will be: ");
            Console.WriteLine(locationOfSshKey);
            Console.Write("is this ok (y/N): ");
            var ok = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!ok.ToLowerInvariant().Equals("y"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key was not created");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            return locationOfSshKey;
        }

        private static void CheckStateOfSshDirectory(string homePath, out string sshDirectory, out string configLocation, out bool configFileExists)
        {
            sshDirectory = $"{homePath}/.ssh";
            configLocation = $"{sshDirectory}/config";
            configFileExists = false;
            if (!Directory.Exists(sshDirectory))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not find .ssh directory ({sshDirectory})");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            configFileExists = File.Exists($"{sshDirectory}/config");
            Console.WriteLine($"Checking whether ssh config file exists {configLocation}: {configFileExists}");
        }

        private static string GetHomePathOrExit()
        {
            string homePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOME");
            if (homePath == null || !Directory.Exists(homePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not find HOME environment variable or HOME path does not exist");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }

            return homePath;
        }

        private static void ValidateCompatibility()
        {
            bool isWindows = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows);
            if (isWindows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Windows is not yet supported");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```